# open document programmatically from UserDefaults in UIDocumentBrowserViewController

Tags: nsfilemanager, uidocument, uidocumentbrowservc

I am working on a document based app in swift using `UIDocumentBrowserViewController`.  I would like the app to default to opening the previous file that was used in the last session.  When exiting the app I save the file URL in UserDefaults.  When I restart the app, `UIDocumentBrowserViewController` presents its view.  I would like to add in `viewDidLoad()` an if-statement that checks if a `fileURL` exits in `UserDefaults`.  If it does I would like to select that file, open it and present it. The simplest approach would seem to be to figure out how to piggyback off of the existing `presentDocument(at: documentURL)` methods I am using with `UIDocumentBrowserViewController`, or perhaps off of one of the UIDocumentBrowserViewControllerDelegate methods; In the other words I would like to programmatically select a file in `UIDocumentBrowserViewController` and present it.   However, when I try this the document fails to open, in the `UIDocument` method `open(completionHandler: )` (i.e. the completion handler reports a failure).  I am sure I have the correct fileURL, also the file I am attempting to do this with is in the cloud directory  Any Ideas on how this should be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out you have to use a bookmark instead of a URL.  The code to create a bookmark and save it to `UserDefaults` is as follows:

```
do {
    let bookmark = try (document.fileURL as NSURL).bookmarkData(options: .suitableForBookmarkFile, includingResourceValuesForKeys: nil, relativeTo: nil)         
    UserDefaults.standard.set(bookmark, forKey: "bookmark")
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Set Bookmark Fails: \(error.description)"
}
```

and the code to retrieve the bookmark, convert it to a URL, and present the document is as follows:

```
if let bookmarkData = (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "bookmark") as? NSData) {
    do {
         let url = try NSURL.init(resolvingBookmarkData: bookmarkData as Data, options: .withoutUI, relativeTo: nil, bookmarkDataIsStale: nil)
         url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
         presentDocument(at: url as URL)
    } catch let error as NSError {
         print("Bookmark Access Fails: \(error.description)")
    }
}
```